# getArguments() returns null Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, bundle

I'm trying to use bundle to pass a string value from activity to fragment but getArguments() returns null so it dosent work for me.
( app starts from MainActivity2)

fragment code:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {


TextView results;
    public ProfileFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setRetainInstance(true);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");
       
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    }
}
```

MainActivity2 code:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
    
    public void Clicked(View view) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("edttext", "From Activity");

// set Fragmentclass Arguments
ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
profileFragment.setArguments(bundle);
Intent intent=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: You didn't put anything in the bundle, that's why it's null

Answer (score 1):

In the first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name", name);
bundle.putString("my_aa", my_aa);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle != null)
    {
        String name = bundle.getString("name");
        String aa = bundle.getString("my_aa");
    }
```

This code work for activitys but I dont know if it's work for fragments

Comment: it dosent work for fragment